# Jquery ajax setInterval not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to make an ajax request every x seconds. This is the function.

```
function test()
{
    alert("wow");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
}
```

If i call it like this

```
test();
```

it works but if i call it like

```
setInterval(function(){ test(); }, 15000);
```

it will call the first alert and then wont make the ajax call.

Comment: When you call test() directly, did it show you second alert i.e. success?

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER yeah

Comment: I put same code in jsfiddle and its working fine.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong here; you need to show a [mcve]. Also, the alerts suggest that you don't use the console – [open the browser console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) and look for error messages.

Comment: What is the scope of your url variable?

Comment: Working for me definitely issue with your server side code

Comment: @JJJ console says
VM152:157 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at test (eval at globalEval (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:157:11)
    at eval (eval at globalEval (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:169:9)

Comment: @Matt_S global ,i even replaced the variable to string still same error, it has something to do with browser not being able to load jquery before calling the function.

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER if thr was something wrong with server side code then it shouldnt work when called outside setinterval but it does. Plus server side code is nothing but a simple json response  for testing.

Comment: SHould you be calling SetInterval with an anonymous function? Should it be: 
    setInterval(test, 15000);

Comment: Asking this out of curiosity, @Matt_S will that make a difference in how the test function is being called?

Comment: @Matt_S tried, same error "Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at test (eval at globalEval (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:157:11)"

Comment: Something overwrites `$` later in the code. Not much else that can be said without a full example.

Comment: it worked by using full jquery cdn instead of slim version. thanks everyone for helping. It's weird how it was working with slim outside setInterval

Comment: It works fine in [JsFiddle. Check here](https://jsfiddle.net/aman01/aey2j01d/)  Go to this link and click Run.

Comment: Most likely you are including the full jQuery before this code at the start of the HTML page, then the slim version some time after it at the end of the page. Without the timer the slim version didn't have time to load yet, with the timer the slim version loaded and overwrote the full version. Now you're loading jQuery twice.

Comment: "It's weird how it was working with slim outside setInterval –". That can't have been happening. Impossible, unless you did something really weird like JJJ suggested just above. Just use full jQuery, you can't use the slim version if you want ajax. Make sure you only ever load jQuery (or any other JS library file) once per page (including even different versions / builds of the same thing).

Comment: @JJJ You are right , i was loading static files "{% load staticfiles %}" and jquery was present in one of the folders.

Comment: @ADyson yup , my bad.